# Wordpress Featured Image Can't load

Tags: php, wordpress

I've run into an issue with my featured images on a wordpress blog I am working on. I just migrated this blog to a local environment (using local by flywheel), and I seem to have everything set up and working as expected accept the featured images.

I uploaded all the images, I can see all of the images in the media library, when I select a featured image it selects the image, but the image doesn't show up in the sidebar panel that shows you which image you have selected.

[image]

[image]

It also doesn't load on the front end, but if I inspect the featured image the url is there (if I visit that url it goes to the image), in dev tools it just says it can't load. No other Console errors.

[image]

The blog is set up using a child TwentySixteen theme.

I've tried re-uploading the images and regenerating all the images using regeneration plugins. Nothing seems to be working. I feel like I'm missing some small config setting or something.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inspect says that the image is in location `http://localhost:10005/...` and after that the `srcset` alternative image attribute has location `https://localhost:10005/...`. HTTP and HTTPS cannot be served from the same port. When you click the URL, the browser probably just fixes the protocol, but cannot do the same when loading the image during the page load.

Check your HTTP/HTTPS settings. It is usually easiest to just make everything either HTTP or HTTPS...

Comment: Wow I feel dumb, can't believe I didn't notice that. Got it working now thank you!